# Recursive writing involving arithmetic progression

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion, arithmetic-progressions

I've been trying to figure out this recursion problem but I'm getting stuck trying to find the nth-term sequence for the last recursion. I found one but the second i'm so clueless about. I don't know what algebra manipulation I'm missing but could someone shed some light to it? Is it even possible?

$Definition: $

$$w_0 = a$$
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, w_{n+1} = w_n +b $$
$$ z_0 = w_0$$
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, z_{n+1} = z_n + (w_{n+1})  x^n$$

For $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, w_{n+1} = w_n +b $

The nth-term is: $a + (n)b$

$$w_0 = a$$
$$w_1 = w_0+_1 = w_0 + b = a + b$$
$$w_2 = w_1+_1 = w_1 + b = (a + b) + b = a + 2b$$
$$w_3 = w_2+_1 = w_2 + b = (a + 2b) + b = a + 3b$$
$$....$$
$$w_n = a + (n)b$$

However for $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, z_n+_1 = z_n + (w_n+_1)  x^n$, i don't seem to see the nth-term...

$$z_0 = w_0 = a$$
$$z_1 = z_0+_1 = z_0 + (x_0+_1)x^0 = a + ((a+b)x^0) = a+(a+b)= 2a + b$$
$$z_2 = z_1+_1 = z_1 + (x_1+_1)x^1 = (2a + b) + (a+2b) x^1$$
$$z_3 = z_2+_1 = z_2 + (x_2+_1)x^2 = ((2a + b) + (a+2b) x^1) + (a+3b) x^2 $$
$$....$$
$$z_n = nth-term?$$

Any help would be great appreciated, thanks

**Edit:** Fixed a typo: $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, w_n+_1 = w_n +b $

Answer (score 0):

$$z_{n+1} - z_n = w_{n+1}x^n = (a+b(n+1))x^n$$
$$\frac{z_{n+1} - z_n}{z_{n} - z_{n-1}}=x\frac{a+b(n+1)}{a+bn}$$
$$\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{z_{k+1} - z_k}{z_{k} - z_{k-1}}=\frac{z_{n+1} - z_n}{z_{1} - z_{0}}=x^n\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{a+b(k+1)}{a+bk}=x^n\frac{a+b(n+1)}{a+b}$$
$$z_{n+1} - z_n=x^n(z_1-z_0)\frac{a+b(n+1)}{a+b}=x^n(a+b(n+1))$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (z_{k+1} - z_k)=z_n-z_0=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^n(a+b(n+1))$$
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}nx^n$$
$$\frac{f(x)}{x}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}nx^{n-1}=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^n\right)'=\left(\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}\right)'=\frac{(n-1)x^{n+1}-nx^n+x}{(x-1)^2x}$$
$$\therefore z_n=a+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^n(a+b(n+1))=a+(a+1)\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}+b\frac{(n-1)x^{n+1}-nx^n+x}{(x-1)^2}$$

Comment: Did you make a mistake in the first line = $(w_n + 1)x^n$? It should be (w_(n+1)).. then = (a+bn)x^n, not = (a+1 + bn) x^n. Sorry if the way i wrote the question confused you.

Comment: Okay, I edited the question and also changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Question why is $ = (w_{n+1})x^n) = (a+b(n+1))x^n$ and not just $((a+b(n))x^n$ ? why is there a $+1$?

Comment: Because $w_{n+1}=a+b(n+1)$ as $w_{n}=a+bn$.

Comment: I thought the n-term recursion for $w_{n+1}$ was already defined to be $a+b(n)$? I think that's what you're doing right? sorry just trying to understand: edit:  ohhhhhhhhhhhh sorry. I see it now.